# How to set horizontal progress bar based on total number of minutes in android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Hi I want to set horizontal progress bar width based on total minutes.

**For example**

Total hours 7hrs 30 minutes - > 450 minutes

Xml

```
<ProgressBar
   android:id="@+id/progress_bar_total_sleep"
   style="@style/SleepProgressFill"
   android:layout_width="270dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Please give any suggestion

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you are referring to android:max? And for each passing minute you could add one unit to android:progress. Pretty hard to guess.

Comment: @AdrianComan i don't know how to set width for 450 minutes can you please tell ?

Comment: Can you please post an image of your expected result? do you want to set     450 min as progress?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set `MAX` value of `ProgressBar` by using method `ProgressBar.setMax(MAX_VALUE)` from `JAVA` and from `XML` use attribute `android:max="MAX_VALUE"`.
2. You need to set `Progress` value of `ProgressBar` to show the progress. You can do it by using method `ProgressBar.setProgress(PROGRESS_VALUE)` from `JAVA` and from `XML` use attribute `android:progress="PROGRESS_VALUE"`.

**Here is an example:** `(From XML)`

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar_total_sleep"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="1000"
    android:progress="450"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />
```

**If you want to change MAX and Progress value programmatically, Try this:**

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_total_sleep);

// Max Minute
progressBar.setMax(1000);
// Progress Minute
progressBar.setProgress(450);
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

```
int minutes=450;     
int total = (int) ((timePassed/ minutes) * 100);
progressbar.setProgress(total);
```

Comment: Can you please tell How to set total width for progressbar?

Comment: android:layout_width depends upon your layout design ...it could be android:layout_width="match_parent" also.May I know your exact requirements

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use try using SeekBar,

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="your drawable"
    android:progressDrawable="your drawable"
    android:thumb="your drawable" />
```

you will have to set the duration id you'r getting the duration from mediaPlayer or just get the duration and put it here:

```
seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
```

and the listener:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean
fromUser) { 

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
```

This is what you wanted or I didn't understand you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 10));
```

here 100 is width and 10 is height

instead of 100 give your total minutes as integer